# Separating the rows with 2 or 3 words using regex in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe with many rows, which has a structure similar to this example one, df.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
data = [{'teams':'Tampa Bay Lightning','league': 'NHL'}, {'teams': 'Toronto Maple Leafs', 'league': 'NHL'}, {'teams': 'Boston Bruins', 'league': 'NHL'},
       {'teams':'Florida Panthers','league': 'NHL'},{'teams': 'Detroit Red Wings', 'league': 'NHL'}, {'teams': 'Montreal Canadiens', 'league': 'NHL'}] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df
```

[image: original_df]

The strings in the 'teams' columns consist of 2 or 3 words separated by empty space.

I can separate them with regex like this to get, for example

```
df1 = df.iloc[[3,4,5],[0]]  # for 2 words

pattern="(^[\w]*)(?:.* )([\w]*$)"
df1[['place', 'team']] = df1["teams"].str.extract(pattern).head()
df1
 
df2 = df.iloc[[1,4],[0]] # for 3 words
pattern="(^[\w]*)(?:.* )([\w]*\s[\w]*$)"
df2[['place', 'team']] = df2["teams"].str.extract(pattern).head()
df2
```

and then concatenate them back into my dataframe by

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_index()
df
```

to get my result.

As you can see, I have just manually selected the rows by index for each case with .iloc.

Can you help me to write the code with an if condition, that picks the rows with 2 or 3 words from my dataframe, and proceeds to apply my regex?

by the way, I have tried an alternative approach to separate the town's name, yet, again I'm not sure how to deal with 3 words.

```
df['town1'] = df['teams'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[1].strip() if x.count(' ')==2 else x.split(' ')[0].strip())
df
```

thank you.

P.S. grr.. I have just realised that there might be a 3rd possibility.
'Tampa Bay Lightning' should be 'Tampa Bay' as a place and 'Lightening' as a team.

So, for this one, it is like this

```
df3 = df.iloc[[0],[0]]

df3[['place', 'team']] = df3['teams'].str.extract(r'^(\w+(?:\s+\w+)?)\s+(\w+)$')
df3
```

and the result is

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,d3]).sort_index()
```

[image]

So I do need the if condition rather than a one line regex..

Comment: So, do you want to separate `a b` into `a` and `b` and `a b c` into `a` and `b c`?

Comment: Try `df[['place', 'team']] = df['teams'].str.extract(r'^(\S+)\s+(\S+(?:\s+\S+)?)$')`

Comment: wow, thats a cool regex expession! can you decipher the (\S+(?:\s+\S+)?) part for me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
df[['place', 'team']] = df['teams'].str.extract(r'^(\S+)\s+(\S+(?:\s+\S+)?)$')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jEw2XF/1). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` - one or more whitespace chars
- `(\S+(?:\s+\S+)?)` - Group 2: one or more non-whitespace chars and then an optional sequence of one or more whitespace chars and one or more non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: cheers, I've figured it out : ) as it helped me to do  'Tampa Bay Lightning'  as 'Tampa Bay' and 'Lightening'.

Comment: @Bluetail If my answer does not help you solve the issue, please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own regex then following should work:

```
df[['place','team']] = df['teams'].str.extract(r"(^[\w]*)(?:.* )([\w]*\s[\w]*$)|(^[\w]*)(?:.* )([\w]*$)").bfill(axis=1)[[0,1]]
```

I just combined your regex with `|` and then used [`bfill`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.1/pandas/core/generic.py#L6462-L6480) to obtain columns, however I suggest you to tweak regex as it can be done without `bfill` too.

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer a non regex solution, since you'd have to do a little more work anyways to get `['Tampa Bay', 'Lightning']` instead of `['Tampa', 'Bay Lightning']`

You can use NLP to pull out the entities that are locations, city, states with the package [spaCy](https://spacy.io/usage). You COULD create your own model using team names then, but then honestly, if you do that, why not just make a dictionary that maps the teams to their place and team name since that's what you'd essentially be doing in creating a training data set.

Or you could just load a pre-trained model. Now there are still a few exceptions, as it won't pick out `'Tampa Bay'`, it'll only identify `'Tampa'`. '`Carolina`' too, as it doesn't know the context of North or South Carolina for a location, or Carolina could be a person...Just like `Columbus` or `Washington`. And it won't pick out `'New England'`. So you could just make a short list of some unique exceptions (I can't think of any other odd ones).

Before you can load in the pre-trained model, you'll have to download it:

so after:

`pip install -U spacy`

do

`$ python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg`

Then you can load in the model to be used:

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

data = [{'teams':'Tampa Bay Lightning','league': 'NHL'}, {'teams': 'Toronto Maple Leafs', 'league': 'NHL'}, 
        {'teams': 'Green Bay Packers', 'league':'NFL'},{'teams': 'Boston Bruins', 'league': 'NHL'},
        {'teams': 'New England Patriots', 'league': 'NFL'},
        {'teams': 'Carolina Hurricanes', 'league': 'NHL'},
        {'teams': 'Columbus Blue Jackets', 'league': 'NHL'},
        {'teams': 'Vegas Golden Knights', 'league': 'NHL'},
        {'teams': 'Brooklyn Nets', 'league': 'NBA'},
        {'teams': 'Oklahoma City Thunder', 'league': 'NBA'},
        {'teams': 'Tampa Bay Rays', 'league': 'MLB'},
        {'teams': 'Washington Football Team', 'league': 'NFL'},
        {'teams': 'Washington Nationals', 'league': 'MLB'},
        {'teams': 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers', 'league': 'NFL'},
        {'teams':'Florida Panthers','league': 'NHL'},{'teams': 'Detroit Red Wings', 'league': 'NHL'}, {'teams': 'Montreal Canadiens', 'league': 'NHL'}] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 



def split_place_team(row):
    unique = ['New England', 'Tampa Bay', 'Carolina', 'Columbus', 'Washington']        
    teams = row
    if teams.rsplit(' ',1)[0] in unique:
        place = teams.rsplit(' ',1)[0]
        team = teams.rsplit(' ',1)[1]
    elif teams.rsplit(' ',2)[0] in unique:
        place = teams.rsplit(' ',2)[0]
        team = teams.split(' ',1)[1]
    else:
        alpah = nlp(teams.rsplit(' ',1)[0])
        for ent in alpah.ents:
            if ent.label_ == 'GPE':
                start_char = ent.start_char
                end_char = ent.end_char
                place = teams[start_char:end_char]
                team = teams[end_char:].strip()
    #print (place)
    #print(team)
    return [place, team]
    

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda row : split_place_team(row['teams']), axis = 1).to_list(), columns=['place','team']))
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
                       teams league          place            team
0        Tampa Bay Lightning    NHL      Tampa Bay       Lightning
1        Toronto Maple Leafs    NHL        Toronto     Maple Leafs
2          Green Bay Packers    NFL      Green Bay         Packers
3              Boston Bruins    NHL         Boston          Bruins
4       New England Patriots    NFL    New England        Patriots
5        Carolina Hurricanes    NHL       Carolina      Hurricanes
6      Columbus Blue Jackets    NHL       Columbus    Blue Jackets
7       Vegas Golden Knights    NHL          Vegas  Golden Knights
8              Brooklyn Nets    NBA       Brooklyn            Nets
9      Oklahoma City Thunder    NBA  Oklahoma City         Thunder
10            Tampa Bay Rays    MLB      Tampa Bay            Rays
11  Washington Football Team    NFL     Washington   Football Team
12      Washington Nationals    MLB     Washington       Nationals
13      Tampa Bay Buccaneers    NFL      Tampa Bay      Buccaneers
14          Florida Panthers    NHL        Florida        Panthers
15         Detroit Red Wings    NHL        Detroit       Red Wings
16        Montreal Canadiens    NHL       Montreal       Canadiens
```